# How do I print a new dictionary in python that is trying to add two lists together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am currently trying to figure out how to make a function that takes two parameters:
data_items and key_values and adds them together to make a new dictionary.

for example:

```
Parameters:    ([7, 9],[13, 26, 31])
Should return: {13: 7, 26: 9, 31: ''}
return: {13: 7, 26: 9}
```

The output I get is limited to the number of data_items (2 values: 7 and 9). How can I still print any extra key values with empty data values.

I have used the following code:

`newList = dict(zip(key_vals, data_list))`

this returns:
{13: 7, 26: 9}

I have tried converting each list into a dictionary and then created a final dictionary and used the update method but it does not work:

```
newList = dict(zip(key_vals, data_list))
```

I have also tried the following:

```
D = {item for item in zip(key_vals, data_list)}
    D = dict(D)

return D
```

Comment: zip takes the shortest length of lists in parameter. It's a requirement to use it. If you want to do what you want to do, you have to code something to fill the shortest list with '' until both length are equal.

Comment: Is it possible for `data_list` to be longer than `key_vals`? If so, what should the output be?

Comment: So if data_list is to be longer than key_vals then it should not print but if key_vals is longer it should print the key followed by an empty key value (Key: ' ')

Answer (score 4):

You can use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from itertools for this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = [7, 9]
b = [13,26,31]
dict(zip_longest(b, a, fillvalue=""))

>>> {13: 7, 26: 9, 31: ''}
```

Comment: Would there be anyway to do this without having to import zip_longest

Comment: You can get an idea of how to implement such a method with the linked resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use zip_logest, you can write a Dict comprehension like the code below:

```
D = {k:data_list[i] if len(data_list)>i else '' for i,k in enumerate(key_vals)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @KellyBundy, I hope it would be ok to edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

You could first build the dict with all keys and the default value, then update with the given values:

```py
data_list, key_vals = [7, 9],[13, 26, 31]

D = dict.fromkeys(key_vals, '')
D |= zip(key_vals, data_list)

print(D)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3i1ISSxLjczKLS3QUslMr48sSc4oVbBWizXUULGN1og2NdRSMzHQUjA1jubhcgBIpmcklemlF-blAxcUaMB06CurqmkD5GluFqswCJGG46ZpcXAVFmXklGi6aEJuhDoA5BAA)):

```
{13: 7, 26: 9, 31: ''}
```